# jquery change value of input with a html tag

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to change the value of my submit input. but It is not just a plain text. for example the value should be like this

Submit query

Send code

but the problem is when I put a br tag between texts, my html code will print exactly. It is possible to change value with query but with printing every texts even html code with that ...

```
$('input[type=submit]').val('submit<br />send code');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\n` instead as your break

```js
$('input[type=submit]').val('submit\nsend code');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" />
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working in Chrome - the second line of the text is cut off. I can only see the upper parts of the 'd' characters on that line

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Working fine for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Form controls hold only plain text.

You can put markup in a submit button by using a `<button>` element instead of an `<input>` element (then you need to use use `.html()` instead of `.val()` to change it with JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put HTML code in to the value of an input button. However, you can set HTML in a `button` with `type="submit"` applied:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).html('submit<br />send code');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Original value</button>
```